# SUM inside CASE in SQL

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select, case

```
select product_class_code, product_id, product_desc, product_price, price as product_price
CASE product_class_code
     WHEN 2050 THEN (price = product_price + 2000)
     WHEN 2051 THEN (price = product_price + 500)
     WHEN 2052 THEN (price = product_price + 600)
ELSE price as product_price
END
from PRODUCT
order by product_class_code;'

product_class_code
```

Execution finished with errors.
Result:

> near "CASE": syntax error At line 1: select product_class_code,
> product_id, product_desc, product_price, price as product_price CASE

this code is not working.

Write a query to display the product details (product_class_code, product_id, product_desc, product_price,) as per the following criteria and sort them in descending order of category: a. If the category is 2050, increase the price by 2000 b. If the category is 2051, increase the price by 500 c. If the category is 2052, increase the price by 600.

Comment: no permanent change in table required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment inside the `case` is wrong. Remove it and you should be fine:

```sql
CASE product_class_code
     WHEN 2050 THEN (price + 2000)
     WHEN 2051 THEN (price + 500)
     WHEN 2052 THEN (price + 600)
ELSE price
END AS product_price
```

Or, since you need the `price` anyway, you could extract it from the `case` and just use the `case` for the extra you need to add:

```sql
price + CASE product_class_code
             WHEN 2050 THEN 2000
             WHEN 2051 THEN 500
             WHEN 2052 THEN 600
             ELSE 0 
        END
AS product_price
```

Comment: SELECT PRODUCT_CLASS_CODE, PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_DESC, PRODUCT_PRICE,
CASE
 WHEN PRODUCT_CLASS_CODE = 2050 THEN PRODUCT_PRICE + 2000
 WHEN PRODUCT_CLASS_CODE = 2051 THEN PRODUCT_PRICE + 500
 WHEN PRODUCT_CLASS_CODE = 2052 THEN PRODUCT_PRICE + 600
 ELSE PRODUCT_PRICE + 0
END AS price
FROM PRODUCT
ORDER BY PRODUCT_CLASS_CODE DESC;